# How to change specific value of XML attribute using scripting on Mac

Tags: xml, sed, awk

I have been tasked to write a script to change a specific value in an XML file on about 1000 Macs. Clearly this needs to be scripted, and preferably only using tools that are already available on a Mac (i.e. no additional installs needed). The end goal here is to disable IPv6 in a specific file related to active directory. For example:

#### Old file:

```
<IPv4>
    <script>Automatic</script>
</IPv4>

<IPv6>
    <script>Automatic</script>
</IPv6>
```

#### New file:

```
<IPv4>
    <script>Automatic</script>
</IPv4>

<IPv6>
    <script>__INACTIVE__</script>
</IPv6>
```

I have tried searching and have a few sed scripts that get me halfway there, but no where close enough. I can't install any XML parsing programs as this needs to be as automated as possible on all the Macs.

Edit: secondary question-

using either awk or sed, can I count the number of times that it made a change, i.e. counting the number of  instances it found?

Comment: Did my updated answer resolve your second question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `awk`:**

```
awk '/<IPv6>/,/<\/IPv6>/ {sub(/Automatic/,"__INACTIVE__")}1' xml_file > new_xml_file
```

**Using `sed`: In-line editing**

```
sed -i '/<IPv6>/,/<\/IPv6>/s/Automatic/__INACTIVE__/' xml_file
```

**To add counts in the mix:**

```
awk '
/<IPv6>/,/<\/IPv6>/ {sub(/Automatic/,"__INACTIVE__"); if ($0~/__/) count++}1 
END{ print FILENAME, count >>"countfile"}' xml_file> new_xml_file
```

The `END` statement will capture the `Filename` you ran the script on and the `counts` of changes in a file called `countfile` and will keep `appending` to it for your statistical analysis.

Comment: Wow!  That was a quick response and works like a charm!  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I added an alternate `sed` solution. If the solution works for you feel free to up vote and accept the answer. :) Good luck!!

Comment: I am new to SO, but have been on SF a while.  I had forgotten it makes you wait to accept answers.

Comment: Thanks for adding the example using sed.  I swear I had tried something almost exactly like that and it didn't work.  On second thought, I think I had the single quotes in the wrong place.

Comment: Yep, missing or incorrect location of `quotes` can lead to several hours of frustration. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to ask a follow up question, but here goes: using either awk or sed, can I count the number of times that it made a change, i.e. counting the number of <IPv6></IPv6> instances it found?

Comment: I added a quick and dirty way of doing it. Hope that helps!